# TFS 2015 Automatically update packages from custom nuget repository on build

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, tfs-2015

I am working on setting up repository at work. I would like to be able to force the TFS builds to use the latest version of each of our in house packages in a given solution without having to modify each project manually, instead of just using the default package restore behavior. I have seen some things online about using nuget.target to perform this but could not find supporting documents from nuget's website. I am open to just about any approach as long as the ending result is that my build server will ultimately us latest version of our packages automatically. We are using version 3.4.4 of nuget.

Comment: Did you read this: http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore?

Comment: Yes I have but either options only restores the version specified in package config not the latest version available. The is especially a problem if I plan on having a repository for each brach e.i.- (Dev, PreProd, Prod)

Comment: You just need to perform `nuget update` after `nuget restore` (which is always considered a good practice anyway). However what I'd ask is...are you **SURE**? Automatic updates may break compilation and you will deploy a version you didn't even try locally. IF compilation won't break and IF your unit testing will ensure also run-time behavior didn't change THEN it will work as expected (probably?) However updates in 3rd party libraries are a serious thing that should be evaluated and planned, you should do it if and when required...not blindly just because a newer version is available...

Comment: Yes I'm sure this is what I want to happen. I want the build to break if  our if the latest version of our in house packages do not work. This should be indicator to developer to get latest and retest build locally. You run the same risks with any other references in a solution if a developer has not grabbed latest when they are building.As for the update command do I just perform the command after restore using powershell/cmd prompt step in build?  If so it looks like I will have to specify specifically which packages I want to update so I can exclude items outside of our custom repository.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you're using a local custom repository. If you have a local repository and you `update` using `-repositorypath` option then it won't find anything outside that and other packages won't be updated (if you really want fine control you have `-id` option to specify each available package - and command line may be built directly from powershell/batch - but I don't think you need that)

Comment: I think that should work thanks for the help.

Comment: @BrianGrayson Did you have it work? Could you add a answer and accept it, so it will be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to as Adriano Repetti  said which was to add a step to  perform nuget update after nuget restore was  on the build server using the cmd line directives.